# Can you call a method on a class and on an instance of the class?

Tags: python, object, vector, methods

I am trying to make a Vector class, which takes three parameters (x,y,z) to make a vector objet

```
u=Vector(3,-6,2) #Creates a vector you with components <3,-6,2>
```

One thing you can do with vectors is add them.  I am looking for a way to do something like this:

```
u=Vector(3,-6,2)
v=Vector(4,5,-1)
c=Vector.add(u,v) #returns a third vector, the sum of u and v (c = <7,-1,1>)
u.add(v) #modifies u to be the sum of u and v (u = <7,-1,1>)
```

Comment: You should override `__add__` method.

Comment: To answer your exact question - `Vector.add(u,v)` is same as `u.add(v)` - Python inside the `add` function there is no way to differentiate between them (until you use a third argument or some other method).

Answer (score 2):

You can't define both class and instance method with the same name.

However, instead of creating an instance method `.add()`, I would override `__add__` magic function which is called when adding two instances via `+` sign. When Python tries to evaluate `x + y`, it attempts to call `x.__add__(y)`:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Vector: {}, {}, {}>'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, v1, v2):
        return cls(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z)
```

--

```
>>> u = Vector(1, 2, 3)
>>> v = Vector(4, 5, 6)
>>> c = u + v
>>> print c
<Vector: 5, 7, 9>

>>> c = Vector.add(u, v)
>>> print c
<Vector: 5, 7, 9>
```